# How to retrieve username for facebook from sharekit in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sharekit

I am creating an app for Facebook and twitter integration using sharekit. That works fine. But now I want to retrieve the username and password for facebook login. I followed [this link](http://getsharekit.com/docs/#authvalues).

But I am not able to retrieve these..

I can't understand how can use that method and where can i use to retrieve username and password

Can you please guide me if you know.

Comment: I call method authorizationformFields from the (item.shareType == SHKShareTypeText) in SHKFacebook.m   like this             SHKSharer *m_retrieve = [[SHKSharer alloc] init];
  if ([m_retrieve isAuthorized]) {
   [m_retrieve authorizationFormFields];
  }

Comment: Then write the code as  NSString *username = [self getAuthValueForKey:@"username"];NSString *password = [self getAuthValueForKey:@"password"]; in the - (NSArray *)authorizationFormFields  . I am getting null value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can't retrieve a user's Facebook *password*. Hopefully the reasons for this are obvious.

You *can*, however, retrieve the *access token* that your app is granted once you connect your app to a user's Facebook account using ShareKit.

As of this writing, I don't believe ShareKit makes the access token accessible directly, but there's an easy hack to retrieve it.

**Step 1**: Ensure that you're app is authorized to connect to Facebook

```
BOOL isConnected = [SHKFacebook isServiceAuthorized];
```

If you get `isConnected == NO` here, your UI should indicate that the user needs to connect to Facebook to use your sharing features.

**Step 2**: Get the access token in order to access the user's Facebook data

Assuming you got `isConnected == YES` in step 1

```
// Hack into ShareKit's user defaults
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *accessToken = [defaults valueForKey:@"kSHKFacebookAccessToken"];
```

**Step 3**: Bypass ShareKit and make a custom query to the Facebook SDK

Assuming a property in your class such as this one...

```
// Change "strong" to "retain" if not using ARC
@property (nonatomic, strong) SHKFacebook *shkFb;
```

...you can start a Facebook query with something like this...

```
    if ( !fb ) {
        // This is how SHKFacebook instantiates a Facebook object. YMMV.
        self.fb = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:SHKCONFIG(facebookAppId)];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *fbParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     @"name", @"fields",
                                     accessToken, @"access_token",
                                     nil];
    [fb requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andParams:fbParams andDelegate:self];
```

**Step 4**: Implement the Facebook delegate methods

Once the Facebook query's done, it'll notify your object, at which point you can do fancy things such as display the user's name to make it clear whose wall will get posts sent from your app.

You'll need to declare the `FBRequestDelegate` protocol in your .h, of course:

```
#import "Facebook.h"

@interface YourClass : NSObject <FBRequestDelegate>
```

And you'll need to implement (minimally) the success and failure methods from FBRequestDelegate:

```
#pragma mark - FBRequestDelegate

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {

    // Additional keys available in "result" can be found here:
    // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ 
    NSString *username = [result objectForKey:@"name"];

    // Localize if you're at all interested in the global app market!
    NSString *localizedString = NSLocalizedString(@"connected as %@",
                                                  @"Connection status label");

    // The label will read "connected as <username>"
    self.statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:localizedString, username];
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // Handle failure

    // (In our app, we call [SHKFacebook logout]
    // and display an error message to the user with
    // an option to retry connecting to Facebook.)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe clozach's answer is for an older version of ShareKit. In the most recent (as of Jan 30 2012) the method of acquiring the Facebook Access Token provided fails with accessToken always being nil.

```
// Hack into ShareKit's user defaults
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *accessToken = [defaults valueForKey:@"kSHKFacebookAccessToken"];
```

Instead, using

```
NSString *accessToken = [[FBSession activeSession] accessToken];
```

works for me.

Comment: In newer versions of Facebook SDK, you should use this code:  

`NSString *accessToken = [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken]`.    

As `accessToken` property of `FBSession` object is deprecated now.

Answer (score 1):

`ShareKit` uses `FBConnect` internally for authentication. So the values can't be retrieved using the same method as you would for `Twitter`. FBConnect uses a `UIWebView` view to connect to the server while authenticating. After authentication, the app will store a token which can be reused to publish the text until the user discards the token on `Facebook`.

So, the answer is no. You can't get that data.